# POST multiple tags Select2

Tags: php, html, forms, jquery-select2

I'm having difficulty posting the data in my multiselect Select2. I'm either receiving no data (if I append `[]` onto the name) or only one item from the list (if I don't include the `[]` on the name.)

I've tried Varchar and Text on the database side.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <label>Items</label>
        <select multiple class="form-control select2" name="items[]" id="items" data-placeholder="&#32;&#32;Type an item then press enter"
          style="width: 100%;">
        </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
<script> 
$("select").select2({
  tags: true,
  createTag: function (params) {
    return {
      id: params.term,
      text: params.term,
      newOption: true
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

PHP handling

```
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$db = 'cl_db';
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', $user, $pass, $db) or die("Something bad happened.");

$items = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['items[]']);
```

Have tried the above php with `items[]` and just `items`

Any guidance is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: PHP should automatically combine values for `items[]` from the request body into an array.  Could you please share your server-side code, as well as the client-side code that handles the form submission?

Comment: Added that in, thank you.